# OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility MetadataException

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

When trying to create a new migration from TFS 2012 Update 2 to Visual Studio Teams Service, the utility fails on the user mapping screen with the following error:

> com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not
>   instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source
>   1456429486357 ALM TFS 1456429486367, due to OH-TFS-Connector-0068:
>   Following Fields are mandatory to map for
>   http://localhost:9090/TFSService integration : {1}

The service appears to be running fine.  Any ideas?

More information form the OpsHub.log file:

```
02/25/2016 13:44:47,511 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl) - OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source 1456429486357 ALM TFS 1456429486367, due to OH-TFS-Connector-0068: Following Fields are mandatory to map for http://localhost:9090/TFSService integration : {1}
com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source 1456429486357 ALM TFS 1456429486367, due to OH-TFS-Connector-0068: Following Fields are mandatory to map for http://localhost:9090/TFSService integration : {1}
    at com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl.getProjectsMeta(TFSMetadataImpl.java:64)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$171aa598.CGLIB$getProjectsMeta$5(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$171aa598$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b1d799e5.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.caching.MetadataCacheHandler.intercept(MetadataCacheHandler.java:38)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$171aa598.getProjectsMeta(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.getUserList(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:1041)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl.getUserList(ConfigServiceImpl.java:394)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b0a3c7db.CGLIB$getUserList$18(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b0a3c7db$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d110172b.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ServiceInterception.intercept(ServiceInterception.java:48)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b0a3c7db.getUserList(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigService.getUserList(ConfigService.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Edit 1:**
Value of _JAVA_OPTIONS:

> -Dhttp.proxyHost=ourserver.ourcompany.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=domain\user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password -Dhttps=false

Comment: Is the machine behind proxy?

Comment: Yes we are behind a proxy server, but we have added the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable with the required settings.  I have edited the question with an example of the environment variable we are using.

Comment: You will have to bypass localhost in your proxy settings. The TFS Service is running locally but your machine will route the request through proxy if local address is not bypassed. Refer C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\ProxyUtility.zip and use it to set proxy configuration along with local bypass host set to default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy utility suggestion worked as described by @OpshubInc. in their last comment.  I have put the suggestion below for future reference.

> You will have to bypass localhost in your proxy settings. The TFS
>   Service is running locally but your machine will route the request
>   through proxy if local address is not bypassed. Refer C:\Program
>   Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration
>   Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\ProxyUtility.zip and use it to set
>   proxy configuration along with local bypass host set to default